# Angles — (simple?) geometry problem

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, angle

Is there any way to calculate the angle $\varepsilon$?

[image]

Here is an even simpler solution without using the inscribed angle theorem:

[image]

Comment: Is $M$ the center of the circle?

Comment: Yes. So it's an isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the inscribed angle theorem.

Comment: 76/2 = 38? So $\varepsilon$ is 66 degrees. So obvious, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both angles are belong to arc $BC$
[image]